# Converting single coulmn data into multiple columns in plsql

Tags: plsql

Item    LOCATION

```
R11565   D11
R11565   D12
R11565   D14
R11565   D15
```

I want output as

```
Item    Location1  Location2 Location3 Location4
R11565   D11          D12      D13       D14
```

Comment: Could you show us the code you have already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use pivoting logic here with the help of `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Item, LOCATION, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY LOCATION) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    Item,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN LOCATION END) AS Location1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN LOCATION END) AS Location2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN LOCATION END) AS Location3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN LOCATION END) AS Location4
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    Item;
```